# Get Value from JSON Request in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel

I get a response in my routes.php, this response is a JSON, this is my code:

```
Route::post('/prueba', function(){
     if(Request::ajax()){    
    echo Response::json(Request::all());       
    }
 });
```

When I make an echo from this I get all this in my console:

[image]

What I need to get just the value from auction_price for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Route::post('/prueba', function(){
 if(Request::ajax()){    
echo Response::json(Request::get('auction_price'));       
}
});
```

Comment: This !, Thanks, I was trying with this: Response::json(Request::only('auction_price'));  thanks !!!

Comment: if this helps you,make it accepted,it will helpfull for another